# Unable to run project on android emulator but Iphone is fine

Tags: reactjs, android-emulator, frontend, expo

I have been having an issue running my project on the android emulator, I have had several problems and currently, I am facing this:

If there is any additional information required to solve this please do ask. Thanks

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-react-native-adapter'.
Project with path ':expo-core' could not be found in project ':expo-react-native-adapter'.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run project on android emulator but works with Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944753/unable-to-run-project-on-android-emulator-but-works-with-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

make sure the library is linked in the Android side or link it manually

Comment: how do I link it?

Comment: actually my library and files have merged but with conflict, they are linked that's not where the issue comes from if I'm not mistaken